# Xpath on Instagram Stories Circle

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm working on a Instagram stories project and I have been trying to create an `xpath` for the Instagram stories colorful circle, that means that there are stories available to watch.
but couldn't find any way to only select the colorful circle (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0gCn.png), the `xpath` I create select both, the colorful circle, and the white circle (https://i.stack.imgur.com/a24sj.png), that means there aren't any new stories to watch.
can anybody help me with this?

these are the `xpaths` that I have tried so far:

```
//canvas[@height="168"]
//canvas[@style="position: absolute; top: -9px; left: -9px; width: 168px; height: 168px;"]
```

I haven't found anything that styles it to the colorful circle to create an `xpath` with it.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @itronic1990 No

Comment: Add a better screenshot. It is not clear which element in the page you are looking at. Also, add html of this element and its parents.

Answer (score 0):

Below xpath can be used to see **colorful story** :

```
//li[@class='Ckrof']//descendant::canvas[@class='CfWVH']
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but it's not working :( you can see in the picture: https://i.imgur.com/lLfWIxb.png, i always test an xpath on chrome before testing directly on selenium, and both didn't work.

Comment: Where is li tag in the link u have shared ?